# Separate strings into different cells in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

For example, I have a string variable named str. This str has a value of:

```
apple
orange
pineapple
```

Each word is separated by a newVbLine. I want to move it on cells. A1 contains `apple`, A2 contains `orange` and A3 contains `pineapple`.

Thanks.

Comment: What data range do you want to manipulate - do you have existing data in A2, A3 etc?

Comment: if those cells are not empty, do overwriting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below splits strings delimited by `vbNewLine` in column A into column B.

Please change
`ws1.[b1].Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(X)`
to
`ws1.[a1].Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(X)`

if you want to overwrite column A

```
Sub Spliced()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim X
    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
    X = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(ws1.Range(ws1.[a1], ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))), vbNewLine), vbNewLine)
    ws1.[b1].Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(X)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: how do i accept a string variable that contains the text separated by vbNewLine?

Comment: @JaysonTamayo - doesn't this code split as you desire? It does need to a be a `vbNewLine`?